# Angular2 with Lumen no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, cors, lumen

I am trying to create API, which has on frontend angular 2 application and at the backend lumen 5.4.

I already handled with GET request and it is working perfectly, now I have problem with POST request.

At the frontend I use something like this

```
this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return this.http
        .post(`${this.url}${this.createAction}`,JSON.stringify({name: name, lead: lead}), this.headers)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().code)
        .catch(this.handleError)
```

And at the backend my method looks something like this

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->parseData($request->all());

    $character = new Character();
    $character->name = $this->name;
    $character->lead = $this->lead;

    try {
        $character->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['code' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
    return response()->json(['code' => '200', 'message' => 'ok']);
}
```

So i tried using

> https://gist.github.com/danharper/06d2386f0b826b669552
>   https://github.com/neomerx/cors-illuminate
>   https://gist.github.com/ardani/168015be6e0f789f0e09efc10ce54810

I also tried to send headers manually from both side, and still I have the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/AngularJS/LaravelWithAngular2App/Lumen_Backend/public/create/. Redirect from 'http://localhost/AngularJS/LaravelWithAngular2App/Lumen_Backend/public/create/' to 'http://localhost/create' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

so, what am I doing wrong, why I have something like redirect when I do not redirect ?

P.S

the variables name and lead exists in frontend, and route is correct

Comment: You CORS headers need only be set in the backend (lumen app or your webserver). They also need to be send in OPTIONS method in addition to both GET and POST

Comment: yeah, and as I said, I am sending access-control-allow-origin header ...

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the problem for the CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :-

1. First you need to create a Middleware "CorsMiddleware.php"

> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next){
>     $headers = [
>        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  => '*',
>        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
>        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true',
>        'Access-Control-Max-Age'          => '86400',
>        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'];    
>     if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
>     {
>         return response()->json('OK', 200, $headers);
>     }    
>     $response = $next($request);
>     foreach($headers as $key => $value)
>     {
>         $response->header($key, $value);
>     }    
>     return $response;
> }
> ```

and add above code in your CorsMiddleware.php

2. Now you have to register your Middleware in App\Http\Kernel.php

   protected $middleware = [
      ...
      \App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
   ];

I hope it will help you.